# Minecraft block lag 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just loaded up a world in the 1.9 update which just came out, and went to chop a tree and it took 4+ seconds with my gaming computer for the block to drop and this is getting really annoying. I have already tried updating Java and turning VBOs on. Fixes?

Comment: Do you have mods enabled?

Comment: Could you press `SHIFT` + `F3`, then take and upload a screenshot?

Comment: Guys, try the 1.9 update for yourself, the block lag is real, and unfortunately there's nothing that could be done.

Comment: Check if this issue is in the bug list on the mojabg site. If so waut a few updates and it will be fixed by the mojang crew

Comment: @Frank 1.9 mods do not currently exist.

Comment: @KeithM This is false

Comment: How do I put an image up?

Comment: And I dont have mods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning smooth lighting to minimum fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I have smooth lighting none